# What is a scalable approach towards fetching data (lookup from) a long list?

Tags: sql, rdbms

Given a simple entity like, say, `User` where each user has a corresponding `user_id`, what is the best way to fetch all users given a list of `user_ids`.

For a small enough list (probably, under 100 elements), I could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (...);
```

The query being generated from whatever language/framework I am using. But, what happens when this list is really big? Also, what should I ideally consider a *small enough* list? For a long list, I could probably do somethig like (example in Java8):

```
List<CompletableFuture<List<User>> usersFuture =
    ListUtils.partition(userIds, 100)
             .map(x -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                 db.fetchUserFromIds(x);
             ))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());

List<User> users =
    CompletableFuture.allOf(SomeUtils.toArray(usersFuture)).thenRun(x -> 
        usersFuture.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList())
    ).get();
```

The only one advantage of this approach is that it is parallelized, and will run upto `size/100` parallel computations (or lesser, depending on the pool size). However, the above is a simple example. A production-ready code would require it to take care of errors, and recovery, possible retries of sublists etc.

What are the other ways you would recommend to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer using sql execution planner to decide the best way to write the query. like :

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id IN (...);
```

for the above query it will use `SEEK` execution plan(mostly), which is best in case of small amount of records but when it comes to large amount of records it will give performance nightmare.

same select statement can be written in different way also. like :

```
SELECT * FROM users u 
inner join [table1] t1 ON u.user_id = t1.user_id ;
```

this might give you `SCAN` execution plan for large no of records, Which is faster than `SEEK`.

Answer (score 0):

I would insert all matching userid into a temporary table that dissolves on commit and then join the temp table and the users table